# Take n elements, and continue while condition is true

Tags: rust, iterator

I have an iterator containing say a number and some data, ordered by timestamp.

I'd like to take the first n elements, and continue on while the timestamp of the following elements are the same.

For example in case of:

```
  (1, "foo"),
  (2, "bar"),
  (2, "bar2"),
  (3, "baz"),
  (3, "baz2"),
  (3, "baz3").
  (5, "qux")
```

take_n_and_while_timestamp_matches(1) would take 1 elements: timestamps 1
take_n_and_while_timestamp_matches(3) would take 3 elements: timestamps 1 and 2
take_n_and_while_timestamp_matches(2) would also take 3 elements: timestamps 1 and 2
take_n_and_while_timestamp_matches(4) would take 6 elements: timestamps 1 and 2 and 3
take_n_and_while_timestamp_matches(100) would take all elements: timestamps 1 and 2 and 3 and 5.

I'd need this to be able to later easily paginate the values. For continuation, I'd only need to fetch a batch of items with timestamp > last_seen_timestamp, no fuss. Workarounds such as storing the number of elements returned in a particular timestamp in the continuation data is not good enough, because if the timestamp is actually the current timestamp, new items may arrive before it is fetched again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that your timestamps are `Clone`able (needed because we cannot store a reference in `last`) you can use [`take_while`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.take_while) to take items while an arbitrary condition holds.

```rust
fn take_n_and_while_timestamp_matches<T: Eq + Clone, V> (it: impl IntoIterator<Item = (T, V)>, mut n: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = (T, V)> {
    let it = it.into_iter();
    let mut last = None;
    it.take_while(move |(t, _)| {
        if n == 0 {
            return Some(t) == last.as_ref();
        }
        n -= 1;
        last = Some(t.clone());
        true
    })
}
```

Comment: Wound up using `scan`, since it kinda does what I want it to do without having to add a specific function for this use case.

`.scan((0, SystemTime::UNIX_EPOC), |state, e| { if state.0 < BATCH_SIZE || e.time() == state.1 { *state = (state.0 + 1, e.time()); Some(e) } else { None } })`

Comment: But your answer is almost on spot, so giving you the green checkmark.